# Accessing the Hot Network Questions via the API

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, api

Currently, there is no public API to access the Hot Network Questions. Can this ability be added to the official API?
Ideally, this method call should return an array of questions, though each question would need to include a [site object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site), which they currently do not.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the sidebar, not the [SE homepage Hot Questions list](http://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy No, I'm talking about the homepage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If parsing an XML is not an issue, Stack Exchange has an Atom feed for Hot Network Question on https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions. However, it seems it's only limited to 30 questions (who knows why).

Example content:

```
<entry>
    <id>https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90615/investment-strategy-for-google-what-did-i-do-wrong</id>
    <re:rank scheme="https://stackexchange.com">68</re:rank>
    <title type="text">Investment strategy for Google: What did I do wrong? &#8211; money.stackexchange.com</title>
    <category scheme="http://money.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="stocks" />
    <category scheme="http://money.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="stock-analysis" />
    <category scheme="http://money.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="stock-markets" />
    <category scheme="http://money.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="google" />
        <author>
        <name>Sonu Mishra</name>
        <uri>https://money.stackexchange.com/users/67805/sonu-mishra</uri>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90615/investment-strategy-for-google-what-did-i-do-wrong" />
    <published>2018-02-09T05:20:33Z</published>
    <updated>2018-02-09T08:06:45Z</updated>
    <summary type="html">
        [redacted]
    </summary>
</entry>
```

---

Alternatively, for JSON lover, <s>the official SE mobile apps retrieve them from https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile</s> due to [the decommisioning of mobile apps infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/241919), [as per 16 Nov 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/updated-mobile-app-infrastructure-has-been-decommissioned#comment1280012_383125), the API is now on https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json (the old mobile link will automatically redirect here). This will also return all 100 questions, the same as [Stack Exchange's homepage](https://stackexchange.com/).

Example content:

```
[
    {
        "site":"money.stackexchange.com",
        "question_id":90615,
        "title":"Investment strategy for Google: What did I do wrong?",
        "display_score":71.336198174178534,
        "icon_url":"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/money/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "creation_date":1518153633,
        "answer_count":2,
        "user_name":"Sonu Mishra",
        "tags":["stocks","stock-analysis","stock-markets","google"]
    }, ...
]
```

Comment: This works, though a public API would definitely be nice. Since it's in the mobile app, I guess the API endpoint won't really change too much...