# History of Hot Questions

Tags: support, hot-questions

Is there a historical list of all questions that have ever been to the Hot Questions list? For the purpose of exploring the most interesting questions (by HQ algo's opinion).

*Regarding [linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list): I'm not asking for all the meta information about dates and times of questions entering and leaving the hot list. I just want the questions.*

Comment: +1, but seems to be a duplicate of [Add an audit log to record when particular question enters and leaves hot list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list).

Comment: uhh… My question is pretty straightforward, and the thing you linked is pretty specific, and about more than I'm asking for. I think what I'm talking about is much easier to do than that.

Comment: Do you want questions from any particular SE site?

Comment: All of them. Filtering would be a nice feature though.

Comment: Related: [How to see if a question was a “hot network question”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271213/295232)

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: As of [February 28, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643/295232), new Hot Network Questions will get an entry in the revisions/post history table, with type 52. You can use the API (and probably SEDE as well) to search for these events.

---

As indicated in [an answer to the linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238531/295232), there is no such official list and it's not likely that there ever will be one.

The closest you can get is community projects regularly scraping the HNQ list. As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/295232), I have one which does this once every 10 minutes since August 4th this year. There's a [PostgreSQL database backup](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/tree/master/hnq-research) of the data up to September 2nd; I will try to update it regularly in the future. The `questions` table will contain the site, ID and title of the question; you can obtain other data via the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) or the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).