# iOS app shows “selected for hot network question” in revision history as 52

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, hot-questions, mobile-app

This was implemented [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/416943).

On a revision history of a post in the iOS app this shows 52:

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1.4 (Build 16D57)

Comment: Clearly we just need to rework the history event numbers so that it's 42 instead of 52 and then all will be clear.

Comment: 52 times better than the android app, which doesn't even have revisions list. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This has been fixed as seen here:

[image]