# Automatically tag hot network questions as such

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Over on Sustainability.SE, [we've been keeping track of questions that hit the HNQ](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/have-any-sustainability-se-questions-ever-made-it-to-the-hot-network-questions-l) whenever we find them. We're a small site, and like getting on the list because it brings in new users. Case in point -- two questions today hit the HNQ, and already some of the users that were attracted have written some good questions and answers.

Currently, you can tell if a question is on the HNQ list by [checking its revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/346823). This is useful if you're looking at a question and it feels a bit hot. However, you can't find this without looking at each question, and for those with no revisions you have to key in the right URL.

**Would it be possible to automatically add a `[tag:HNQ]` to these questions?**

It seems that this could be useful for anyone reviewing the question who *didn't* get there from the sidebar list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324641/now-you-can-know-if-a-question-really-hit-the-hnq) - if there's a feature to be added (like auto-tagging, instead of or in addition to a history entry), it should be requested there in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, you can't find this without looking at each question, and for those with no revisions you have to key in the right URL.

I have two options for you to make this a lot easier:

## Use SEDE!

With a little SQL magic and the help of SEDE, you can actually pull up all of your HNQ questions pretty quickly. I mocked up a query to do just that. [See it here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/sustainability/query/1149151/hnq-hits)

This is possible because HNQ inclusions (and removals) were added as a new Post History type.

Note that since the SEDE db is updated every Sunday, you may be a little behind looking at this data. So I'd use this more as a historic view.

If you want to know right when you have questions hitting the list, then...

## Use RSS!

If SEDE is really not enough, you can hook into this third party HNQ RSS feed: http://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/

I've seen this hooked up to a few chatrooms around the network so anyone in the chatroom is notified the instant a new question on the site goes Hot.

Comment: Except that with SEDE you'll probably be the last to know about HNQs, since the data's only updated on Sundays.

Comment: Good call @Laurel, edited that in to make it more clear of the use cases for SEDE vs. RSS. Thanks!