# Why does this question have 26 "entered HNQ" revision entries?

Tags: bug, hot-questions, revisions-list

I answered a question on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, which I noticed had gotten a relatively large amount of votes. I figured it had probably gone HNQ, and went to check the [revision history of the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/236947/revisions) (spoilers for *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, BTW). I found out that boy yeah it had gone HNQ:

[image: Screenshot of the revision history, showing a lot of "Became Hot Network Question" events]

All in all, there were 26 entries for "Became Hot Network Question" in the post revision history.

Which... seems odd, since I'm pretty sure there's only supposed to be [one event ever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324641/now-you-can-know-if-a-question-really-hit-the-hnq#comment1060437_324643). This seems like a bug; there *probably* shouldn't be 26 different entries for a question hitting HNQ.

Comment: +1 for the title, which does a better job describing the bug than the older question of which this is, without a doubt, a duplicate.