# Can I see my questions or answers that are or had been listed on Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I wonder if I can see all my questions and answers that are currently on or had been previously listed on the 'Hot Network Questions.'

When I see a revision history of a specific question, I know whether it was listed on Hot Network Questions, but I wonder if I can see all of them altogether in a single page.

Comment: Such a feature does not exist yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That kind of information can be retrieved via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), at least for hot questions since [February 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/295232). I created [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1702438/potential-hnq-post-by-a-specific-user-network-wide?AccountId=1529456) which checks this for a single user, network-wide. It is not recorded when a question *leaves* the Hot Network Questions list, so it could be that an answer was posted afterwards; you can compare both dates to check.

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results could be a bit stale.

Comment: This is great! Just as a potential simplification in the future, here's a version of the first query that executes [dynamic SQL in the context of each database](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1702483) without having to do all that string concat with the database name. Cursor vs. string concat is kind of "pick your poison" I guess, even though the SQL string building is a cursor in disguise, but I like this way better because you can take the dynamic SQL and debug it independently.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I can never remember the correct syntax for `CURSOR`, that's why I chose this strategy, and if the query itself is complicated I'll test it out on a single site first, but most of the time the first iteration is (almost) right.

Comment: You can do the same without a cursor, but it's... a lot uglier.